# GWT + Phonegap Cross domain Requests not working

Tags: gwt, cordova, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm having trouble with making HTTP Requests using GWT 2.4 (and JQueryMobile jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js, but not for anything related with the calls) on Phonegap 1.1.0. What I want to do is to use the POST method on another server in order to receive content and display it.

On the desktop it's working fine (thanks to a reverse proxy configuration). On Phonegap, I read that ["the cross-domain security policy does not affect PhoneGap applications. Since the html files are called by webkit with the file:// protocol, the security policy does not apply."](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494770/FAQ). However, it seems that the request is never made on the phone, as the response is empty and the status code 0 - a similar behavior that I experienced before I solved the cross domain issue on the desktop.

I'm using the regular RequestBuilder on GWT to send my requests. Any ideas on why this is happening? All the permissions on Phonegap are active.

**edit**: Here is my Java code that sends the request, from which I omitted my soap envelope:

```
    RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST,url);
    rb.setHeader("SOAPAction", "assertIdentityWithSimpleAuthentication");
    rb.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    String envelope = "etc"; //this is my soap envelope, 

    try{
        rb.sendRequest(envelope, new RequestCallback() {
         public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
             requestFailed(exception);
          }
         public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
             if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){
                 String aid = Tools.parseMessage(response.getText(),"assertionId"); //this just parses the response in order to get the string I need
                 Window.alert("Sucess: "+ aid);
                 sendAssertionID(aid); //and sends it to another function
             }
             else setError(response);
          }
      });
      } 
        catch (RequestException ex) {
          requestFailed(ex);
      }
```

Comment: I am using http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/ for quite some apps, but don`t have any issues with Requestbuilder can you post some code of yours?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Daniel, I updated my question with the code. I am not using GWT-Phonegap at the moment, I'm just using the exported GWT material on my Phonegap project at the moment.

Comment: sorry i forgot to ask which plattform you are running on: android, ios.... another thing just got to mind you load a local index.html file?

Comment: I'm on Android, and yes, Phonegap loads a local html file.

Comment: this works perfectly fine on my android devices, but if i do something  fishy to the url I also get your behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your url. Your code works fine on my android devices, but fails with an invalid url with code 0.

It needs to start with http:// or https://

Comment: My URL starts with http:// and is a server on my network, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't exactly the problem BUT your answer helped me getting there :) The problem was that the Android system isn't, for some reason, recognizing the name of my server. After your answer, I remembered to check on both emulator and my terminal if I could access the server on browser, and it didn't! Using the local IP instead of the URL solved the problem. Thank you so very much, if you didn't mention the URL I would surely still be stuck!